# Configuring Angular2 router with children gives error when navigating to parent without child path

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm configuring Angular2 router 3.0.0-alpha.8 like this:

```
{ path: 'Person', component: PersonComponent, 
    children: [{ path: 'Address', component: AddressComponent}] }
```

Where PersonComponent has a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag.

When navigating to "localhost:4200/Person/Address" the AddressComponent is displayed correct embedded in the PersonComponent.

Sometimes I would like to hide the AddressComponent, but when navigating to "localhost:4200/Person" an exception is thrown: Error: Cannot match any routes: 'Person'

Is it possible to configure the router, so I can use the router to hide and show the child component?

Comment: Is the spelling of Adress in `component: AdressComponent` intentional or a typo?

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo. Should be fixed now.